# Selective printing of file

Tags: shell, unix

I have a file from which I have to do selective printing. I want to print everything from a particular tag till the end. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you havent googled this. :)

You can use AWK and SED Utilities to get this done.

**AWK:**

```
awk '/regex/,0' INPUTFILE
```

This one liner matches all lines with pattern that is in your regex. Pattern two is 0 which will always be false and hence awk will continue printing lines starting from your matched pattern to the end of file.

**SED:**

```
sed -n '/regex/,$p' INPUTFILE
```

This is similar to awk in terms of Regex range. This matches everything from your pattern to the end of file and prints it.